# Can a CPU have a max compatible RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu

I found some specs about my laptop that says it comes with 512MB of RAM and is upgradeable to 2GB.  I have 4GB of RAM that I'm planning on putting in it, but I'm wondering if its possible for it not to work - Can a CPU have a maximum amount of RAM that it can handle, or did I just find some old specs from when 4GB wasn't a thing?

Comment: No, its the motherboard that has max compatible RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both can be correct.
The maximum amount of RAM can be limited by the CPU itself, by the motherboard chipset and by the BIOS.
Often it is a combination of those that determines the maximum amount a system can technically support.

It happens that, at the time of production, larger RAMs where not yet available, even though the system could in theory use them.
Because the manufacturer couldn't test with those larger modules they are not mentioned in any documentation and they are not officially supported.
 In some cases the manufacturer actually blocks the use of untested modules by putting a limitation in the Bios.
So they may work or not. The only way to know is to try.

What it comes down to: If you happen to have such modules laying about it can't hurt to try to see if they work. But I wouldn't go out and spend money to buy any without knowing for sure.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work.

Modern CPUs implement their Memory controller internally, so they do set limits on the amount of RAM. http://ark.intel.com/ is the official place to get specs on intel CPUs, and they list a Memory limit on each chip. See [here](http://ark.intel.com/products/75122/Intel-Core-i7-4770-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_90-GHz) for an example, and pay attention to the Max Memory Size.

The chipset implemented by the motherboard will dictate the number of slots per channel, the number of channels, and how those channels are accessible to a given CPU socket (very important in multi-socket boards). see an example here (the Z170 chipset): http://ark.intel.com/products/90591

Back to your specific concern, The Chipset/motherboard the manufacturer chooses and the BIOS/Firmware they ship are paired specifically, in that the firmware often has expectations about the amount of ram that can be addressed. I had to get a bios update from HP on the last system I upgraded ram on, because the stock one would not recognize volumes of RAM that both the CPU and Motherboard supported.